# Issue with insert after subquery - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, common-table-expression

I've a sub list of subqueries something like below

```
WITH QRY1 AS (.. SOME PL SQL STATEMNT),
QRY2 (.. SELECT X,Y,Z,QRY1.* ),
QRY3 (.. SOME SELECT * AGAIN USING QRY2)
```

and finally

```
SELECT * FROM QRY3;
```

is there a way that I can do

```
INSERT INTO table_name (a,b,c,d)
     SELECT * FROM QRY3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the CTE as part of the select, after the insert itself, rather then before it:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (a,b,c,d)
WITH QRY1 AS (.. SOME PL SQL STATEMNT),
QRY2 (.. SELECT X,Y,Z,QRY1.* ),
QRY3 (.. SOME SELECT * AGAIN USING QRY2)
 -- and finally 
SELECT * FROM QRY3;
```

Quick demo:

```
create table table_name (a number, b number, c number, d number);

insert into table_name (a,b,c,d)
with qry1 as (select 4 as d from dual),
qry2 as (select 2 as b, 3 as c, qry1.* from qry1),
qry3 as (select 1 as a, qry2.* from qry2)
select * from qry3;

1 row inserted.

select * from table_name;

         A          B          C          D
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3          4
```